# Jenkins Amazon EC2 plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

**Configure Clouds**

Remote FS root: /home/ec2-user

Remote user:    ec2-user

Labels:         OnDemand

Test connection: Success.

EC2 plugin can successfully provision an EC2 instance and start the Jenkins slave if the Jenkins' project does not use git. If I use git, I got,

```
Error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/home/ec2-user/workspace/demo1"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

**Project Configuration**

Restrict where this project can be run

Label Expression: OnDemand

Source Code Management

Git

Repositories Repository URL:  Some URL

Credentials:                  Some Credentials

git init /home/ec2-user/workspace/demo1 # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/home/ec2-user/workspace/demo1"): error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jGit (Jenkins git client plugin). It solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).